# What is the literary device used here?

Tags: figurative-language

I remember my teacher talking about literary devices, I have a sentence below. What literary device is use here?

> To bring peace, you must bring war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [paradox is used here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox).

> A paradox is a statement that, despite apparently valid reasoning from true premises, leads to an apparently-self-contradictory or logically unacceptable conclusion. A paradox involves contradictory-yet-interrelated elements that exist simultaneously and persist over time.
>
> <sup>*(from Wikipedia)*</sup>

The sentence you cited has opposite contradictory-yet-interrelated elements: "peace" and "war". On first sight, war does not bring peace, yet this statement says otherwise.

That sentence actually [originated from a Latin author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Si_vis_pacem,_para_bellum) and was translated.

> The phrase is used above all to affirm that one of the most effective means to ensure peace for a people is always to be armed and ready to defend oneself.

Here are more examples of paradox:

- I must be cruel to be kind.
- In order to lead, you must follow.
- To save money, you must use it.

Comment: This is apparently a specific literary usage of "paradox".  An actual paradox is actually self-contradictory.  It doesn't just have an initial appearance of being self-contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

It is an oxymoron, a figure of speech that combines contradictory phrases. It may not be a paradox formally because there is no necessity that the contradiction be the result of a logical argument. It is perhaps an implied paradox.

Comment: My understanding of *oxymoron* was that the contradicting terms had to be next to each other, e.g. “sunny night” or “falsely true”. And *paradox* is broader than just the formal term in logic. Perhaps some definitions might resolve this (and add weight to your answer)?

Comment: @chappo The article in Wikipedia does not agree with your narrow definition, but merely says that adjective-noun combinations are the most common form of oxymoron. Webster's gives two definitions. The more restrictive definition is "a combination of contradictory or incongruous words" with no mention of adjacency although the example given is of the adjective-noun form. The less restrictive definition does not even mention "words" but rather refers to "elements" such as concepts.

Comment: @chappo I do not disagree that "paradox" has a broader field of meaning than that of formal logic. It seems to me that my answer already takes that into account. But paradox sounds in something being truly contradictory. When DuBallay writes that only the Tiber, fleeing to the sea, "*reste de Rome*," he is playing on different meanings of the word "*reste*" rather than stating a contradiction. He is in fact contrasting Rome as a historical idea and the actual Rome of his day.